# Finding terms in a geometric sequence reaching target remainder

Tags: programming

I want to find how many terms I need to sum such that the resulting expression is smaller or equal than the target remainder. For example:

```
Φ = GoldenRatio^-1;
Alpha = 0.00729735257;
target_remainder = 6.834560434400977`*^-6;

sum = Alpha - (Φ^11 + Φ^13)
(* 0.000352975 *)
sum = Alpha - (Φ^11 + Φ^13 + Φ^17)
(* 0.0000729415 *)
sum = Alpha - (Φ^11 + Φ^13 + Φ^17 + Φ^20)
(* 6.83456*10^-6 *)
```

Therefore, the answer for this particular case should be `{11, 13, 17, 20}`.

I have tried ChatGPT to get the code, but it does not work.

```
(*Define the constants*)
Φ = GoldenRatio^-1;
Alpha = 0.00729735257;

(*Define the target number and the stopping condition*)
target = Alpha; (*replace with your target number*)
stopCondition = 0.000000000001; (*replace with your desired stopping 
condition*)

(*Initialize the chain and the tally*)
chain = {};
tally = target;

(*Loop until the tally is less than the stopping condition or 
becomes negative*)
While[tally >= stopCondition && 
  tally > 0,(*Find the highest power of Φ that does not exceed the tally*)
 n = Ceiling[Log[Φ, tally]] - 1;
 (*Subtract Φ^n from the tally*)
 tally -= Φ^n;
 (*Add n to the chain*)
 AppendTo[chain, n];
 (*If the tally becomes negative,add back Φ^n and break the loop*)
 If[tally < 0, tally += Φ^n;
  Break[];];]

(*Print the chain in the form Φ^n*)
Print[StringJoin[Riffle[ToString[Φ] <> "^" <> ToString[#] & /@ chain, " + "]]];

(*Print the target remainder and the actual remainder*)
Print["Target remainder: ", stopCondition]
Print["Actual remainder: ", tally]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
alpha = 0.00729735257;
remainder = 6.834560434400977`*^-6;

Last@Reap[
  NestWhileList[# - 
     GoldenRatio^(-Sow[Ceiling[-Log[GoldenRatio, #]]]) &, 
   alpha, # > remainder &]]

Clear[alpha, remainder]
```

---

```
{{11, 13, 17, 20}}
```

With `remainder = 10^-10;`:

```
{{11, 13, 17, 20, 25, 29, 41, 43, 46}}
```

For higher precision using exact numbers `729735257/100000000000` instead of `0.00729735257` is recommended.

**Update:**

Or equivalently

`-RealExponent[#, GoldenRatio]` instead of `-Log[GoldenRatio, #]`

Comment: Thank your response was ultrafast and timely.  The solution was much more elegant and insightful than hoped.  Best Wishes.